# how to add virtualization in material ui grid list using react async?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react material ui in an application, but found some missing logic with my react code. The

```
let nums = Array.from(Array(30).keys());

 <GridList cols={3}>
  {nums.map(n => {
    return (
      <GridListTile key={n}>
        <RecipeReviewCard key={n} num={n} />
      </GridListTile>
    );
  })}
</GridList>
```

line shows static cards in a grid list and I want to auto increase the Grid Cards (using virtualization) but I'm a newbie with react. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a grid list cards from here: 
https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/

Application built with

```
{
"react": "16.12.0", 
"react-dom": "^16.12.0", 
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"redux": "^4.0.4"
"@material-ui/core": "^4.7.2"
}
```

The container uses the react component, which is just repeating an a Card.

Output: Grid List shows 30 static cards but grid list should be auto increased and display more cards over vertical scrollbar.

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.